# Property layout_span in tablelayout is not accessible

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using eclipse with java 1.6 and android 3.2 sdk
in textview at first row I'm trying to use layout_span but it's not there
what can cause such a problem

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem :) but could solve it try to change your layout redesing with another layout different from tablelayout

Comment: not important that it isn't there.you can use android:layout_span="" and it will work rightly